# Moving to Canada - Do I need to be physically present when household goods arrive in Canada?

Tags: canada, relocation

I am currently inquiring with movers to move my personal items/household goods from Hong Kong to Canada. I will be flying to Canada around the same time as the moving of my items and hence will arrive in Canada well before my personal effects arrive by sea freight. The freight will go to Vancouver, BC, but I will by the time the items arrive already be at my new home almost 1000km away from Vancouver.

One particular mover, whose service I like and whom I have used before, insists on me having to be personally present when my shipment arrives in Vancouver and undergoes customs clearance. I have never heard of such requirements and it would be a major inconvenience to travel 2000km (two-way) just so I can be physically present at the port of entry of my personal effects. The entire point of using a door-to-door service is to avoid such hassle.

Can someone share from their personal experience or point me to a federal document that states such requirements should it really exist?

Thanks
Matt

Comment: Why not ask a different moving company?

Comment: Because it came directly from the moving company as I clearly mentioned. Other movers did not mention the same "requirement". Hence, asking a mover does not make sense. Either it is a legal requirement or it is not. For someone who needs to drive 20 minutes to the port to meet customs it might not be an issue but for me that would be 2000 kilometers.

Comment: To be clear: Did the company you like claim that it's a *legal requirement* rather than just something the company requires for whatever reason? Have the other companies told you they *don't* need you to be there, or has the topic just not been mentioned yet?

Comment: @ChrisH, the topic has not come up with the other movers we received quotes from, yet. But I intend to follow up with them and specifically ask them about this issue. I just wanted to ask here first to know where the regulation/law stands. The one mover who mentioned it did not say it is a regulation, but also was opaque in not wanting to say this was their own requirement. I assume it is not their own requirement as the mover offers a door-to-door service whereas it has their own team on the ground at the port of entry (not using another mover for the last leg)